# The difference between Mutation and Query

Tags: graphql

I'm reading [GraphQL Docs](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/) about `Query` and `Mutation`. However, there is a lack of real examples which shows the difference and most importantly — when is it appropriate to use them.

Many thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

### Short

Conventionally:

- `Query` — for querying data (`SELECT` operations)
- `Mutation` — for creating new and updating/deleting existing data (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`)

### Detailed

Technically **any GraphQL query could be implemented to cause a data write**. But there is a convention that any operations that cause writes should be sent explicitly via a mutation.

Besides the difference in the semantic, there is **one important technical difference**:

`Query` fields **can be executed in parallel** by the GraphQL engine while `Mutation` top-level fields **MUST execute serially** according to the spec:

> If the operation is a mutation, the result of the operation is the result of executing the mutation’s top level selection set on the mutation root object type. This selection set **should be executed serially**.
>
> It is expected that the top level fields in a mutation operation perform side‐effects on the underlying data system. Serial execution of the provided mutations ensures against race conditions during these side‐effects.

Source: https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Mutation

Answer (score 19):

In simple words the query is SELECT statement and mutation is INSERT Operation.

Query in graphql is used to fetch data while mutation is used for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operation.

Comment: At this point, do i have to commit transactions manually everytime or GraphQL handles it automatically?

Comment: under which category does the "login" operation fall?

Comment: it depends on you where you want to put. but in my case i always put login in Query. because it does not update anything. please checkout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189364/shouldnt-the-login-be-a-query-in-graphql) for more info. and sorry for late reply didn't got notification.

Comment: It is a really really superficial answer. Here on SO, we all should **downvote** answers like this (sorry, author). If you want to post an answer - post something **thoroughly investigated**, like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52551263/1115187)

Comment: actually, this answer is just a comment or a small amendment for the accepted one

Comment: @maxkoryukov Yes this is short answer but if you see the accepted answer is one year later than this. this was the first answer for the question.

Answer (score 11):

**query** = SELECT

**mutation** = INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE

Comment: It is a really really superficial answer. Here on SO, we all should **downvote** answers like this (sorry, author). If you want to post an answer - post something **thoroughly investigated**, like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52551263/1115187)

Comment: actually, this answer is just a comment or a small amendment for the accepted one

Answer (score 8):

think in *REST*:

**query** => *GET*, **mutation** => *POST*, *PUT*, *PATCH*, *DELETE*

Comment: It is a really really superficial answer. Here on SO, we all should **downvote** answers like this (sorry, author). If you want to post an answer - post something **thoroughly investigated**, like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52551263/1115187)

Comment: actually, this answer is just a comment or a small amendment for the accepted one

Answer (score 6):

## Query:

It should be used only for **READ** operations on the database.

## Mutation:

It should be used only when you perform **CREATE / UPDATE / DELETE** something in the database.

## Summary

If you just intend to read data without modifying(means without deleting, editing or creating) anything in your database, use a query.  If you intend to delete, create, anything at database level, use a mutation.

## This is what the documentation says [here](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#mutations):

> In REST, any request might end up causing some side-effects on the
> server, but by convention it's suggested that one doesn't use GET
> requests to modify data. GraphQL is similar - technically any query
> could be implemented to cause a data write. However, it's useful to
> establish a convention that any operations that cause writes should be
> sent explicitly via a mutation.
>
> Just like in queries, if the mutation field returns an object type,
> you can ask for nested fields. This can be useful for fetching the new
> state of an object after an update.
>
> There's one important distinction between queries and mutations, other than the name:
>
> While query fields are executed in parallel, mutation fields run in
> series, one after the other.This means that if we send two
> incrementCredits mutations in one request, the first is guaranteed to
> finish before the second begins, ensuring that we don't end up with a
> race condition with ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from : https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#multiple-fields-in-mutations

> A mutation can contain multiple fields, just like a query. There's one
> important distinction between queries and mutations, other than the
> name:
>
> While query fields are executed in parallel, mutation fields run in
> series, one after the other.

That means, if you run 2 mutations parallelly, second mutation is executed only after completion of first mutation.

Answer (score 2):

I want to share my own experience, maybe it adds value to the above nice answers.

Graphql operations mostly do query a database. Regarding this, a Query can get data with simple select statement which does not modify anything at the db level. But one can also run a stored procedure (spr) or so and get the same data.

When I use a spr, I also create some log records at db side. Sometimes logging spr parameters is necessery for example. Or logging who made the request at db table.

If I need the modifications made by a data request (log records etc) to show to the client, the only way of doing it is using a Mutation, this way I can later select log records and show them to the client app.

If I use a Query the data may be incomplete (log records may be queried before they are created etc.)