# Shouldn't the login be a Query in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

In the [tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/6-authentication/) on GraphQL authentication, the `login` is a **Mutation**:

```
type Mutation {
  post(url: String!, description: String!): Link!
  signup(email: String!, password: String!, name: String!): AuthPayload
  login(email: String!, password: String!): AuthPayload
}
```

Shouldn't the login be a ***Query*** since:

1. The operation has no side-effects on the server.
2. The goal is to *query* a token.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, From my understanding, A mutation is what modifying your data and query is just retrieving so Login should be Query. 

Answer (score 164, accepted):

In the context of that example, `login` should be a Query instead of a Mutation assuming its resolver has no side-effects, at least according to the spec. However, there's a couple of reasons you probably won't see that done in the wild:

- If you're implementing authentication, you'll probably want to log your users' account activity, either by maintaining some data about login/logout events or at least including some sort of "last login" field on the account's record. Modifying that data *would* be a side effect.
- A convention has evolved that treats any operations that result from user actions as Mutations, regardless of side-effects. You see this with `react-apollo`, for example, where `useQuery` fires the associated query on mount, while `useMutation` only provides a function that can be called to fire that query. If you're planning on using Apollo client-side, it's worthwhile to consider those sort of client features when designing your schema.
- Mutations are ran sequentially, while queries are ran simultaneously. That means it'd be foreseeable to fire a login mutation and one or more other mutations after it within the same call, allowing you to utilize an authenticated context for the subsequent calls. The same could not be said for queries -- if `login` is a query and you include other queries with it in the same operation, they will all begin resolving at the same time.

Outside of how they're executed (sequentially vs simultaneously), on the server-side, queries and mutations are effectively interchangeable. You could have queries with side-effects and mutations with no side effects. You probably should stick with conventions, but I think sometimes there's valid reasons where you may have to throw those conventions out the window.

Comment: `Mutations are ran sequentially, while queries are ran simultaneously` this was some good observation. I had no idea about. Thank you. Helps in some decision making on whether to resolve as a mutation or query.

Comment: Note Apollo now have a hook "useLazyQuery" which won't query the data until you trigger manually the load, quite similar to useMutation. But currently it does not return a promise (see https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3499)

Comment: This x 100. If `mutation` was instead called (the admittedly less catchy) "imperative, non-cached query" it would be more apparent that it's exactly what you want in this scenario. If debating semantics is your thing, I highly recommend switching to a REST API where you can drink your fill.

Comment: My colleague throws this answer in my face when we are discussing if a login should be a query or mutation. I can not believe that no one stands out to point out the issue here. See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

No, login should be a mutation.

The 2 assumptions are generally incorrect for a login process.

> 1. The operation has no side-effects on the server.
> 2. The goal is to query a token.

Before login, the token does not exist on both the server and client side.

During login, the token was created by the server and sent to the client side.

After login, the server side accepts one more token that was just created.

So login DO create something. It definitely mutates the system state (by allowing 1 more token in the system).

The illusion that you may think that the login has no side effects it's just because the token is not stored on the server side. Just think the client side is a special database for storing the login tokens.

So

1. The login operation has side effects on the server side, which will accept 1 more token
2. The goal of the login operation is to create a token.

Thus, the login is definitely a mutation, it mutates the whole system.