# Check email / username availability with query or mutation?

Tags: graphql

What is the recommended way to check for username / email availability? Should I use mutation or query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shouldn't the login be a Query in GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189364/shouldnt-the-login-be-a-query-in-graphql)

Comment: @DanielRearden related but no duplicate

Answer (score 3):

According to the official definition of [Mutation](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/).

> If you have an API endpoint that alters data, like inserting data into a database or altering data already in a database, you should make this endpoint a Mutation rather than a Query.

In the case of checking for availability it does not change or create any data, so it should be a Query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did it that way but I wanted to be sure. Thanks!