# Is it a bad practice to use an Input Type for a graphql Query?

Tags: graphql

I have seen that inserting an Input Type is recommended in the context of mutations but does not say anything about queries.

For instance, in [learn tutorial](https://graphql.github.io/learn/schema/#input-types) just say:

> This is particularly valuable in the case of mutations, where you might want to pass in a whole object to be created

I have this query:

```
type query {
    person(personID: ID!): Person
    brazilianPerson(rg: ID!): BrazilizanPerson
    foreignerPerson(passport: ID!): ForeignerPerson
}
```

Instead of having a different type just because of the name (rg, passport) of the fields, or put one more argument like type in query, I could not just have the `Person` with an documentNr field and do an Input type like that?

```
input PersonInput {
   documentNr : ID!
   type: PersonType # this type is Foreign or Brazilian and with this I k 
}
```

`PersonType` is a enum and with him I know if the document is a rg or a passport.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is nothing incorrect about your approach. The GraphQL spec allows *any* field to have an argument and allows any argument to accept an Input Object Type, regardless of the operation. In fact, the differences between a query and a mutation are [largely symbolic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189364/shouldnt-the-login-be-a-query-in-graphql/50190570#50190570).

It's worth pointing out that any field can accept an argument -- not just ones at the root level. So if it suited your needs, you could easily set up a schema that would allow queries like:

```
query {
  person(id: 1) {
    powers(onlyMutant: true) {
      name
    }
  }
}
```