# Whats the point of seprate type mutation for upade functions in graphql?

Tags: graphql

While writing schema in graphql we usually use two separate blocks, `type Query` for simple get queries functions and `type Mutation` for those which will update the server-side data. But when I tried putting my updating function in the schema of simple graphql `type Query`, surprisingly it still worked. I guess having two separate blocks for querying functions and mutating function could bring some clarity to those reading the API but apart from that is there is any real necessity to have mutating functions only in `type Mutation` block?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shouldn't the login be a Query in GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189364/shouldnt-the-login-be-a-query-in-graphql)

Comment: Not an exact dupe, but this question is effectively asking the same thing and the accepted answer sufficiently answers this question.

Comment: no, it's not duplicate. Because the person who has asked that questions already agrees that if the login would have made any changes/side-effect to server side then login should have come inside Mutation. On the other hand, I'm asking why it is such that if something is making changes on the server side then why is it technically necessary to put that inside mutation block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Language.Operations), GraphQL supports three operations:

> - query – a read‐only fetch.
> - mutation – a write followed by a fetch.
> - subscription – a long‐lived request that fetches data in response to source events.

This is the intended usage, but because *how* a field is resolved is left up to the service itself, there's no way an implementation can effectively prevent you from having a query that has side effects or a mutation that is only a read-only fetch.

The only practical difference between a query and a mutation operation is order of execution. Normally, fields within the same selection set are resolved in parallel. [However](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/draft/#sec-Mutation):

> It is expected that the top level fields in a mutation operation perform side‐effects on the underlying data system. Serial execution of the provided mutations ensures against race conditions during these side‐effects.

In other words, here `foo` and `bar` will be resolved in parallel:

```
query {
  foo
  bar
}
```

and here `foo` will be resolved first, then `bar`:

```
mutation {
  foo
  bar
}
```

There's three main reasons to maintain the pattern as established in the spec:

1. To enable consumers of your API to safely execute mutations sequentially, as described above.
2. To avoid issues with clients like Apollo, which make certain assumptions around how a particular operation will be used by the client depending on whether the operation is a `query` or a `mutation` -- for example, react-apollo assumes queries should be ran when the component mounts, while mutations should be triggered by a user action.
3. To follow the spec and established conventions, which avoids unnecessary confusion on the part of consumers of your API or other developers on your team.