# Can Queries be used for data writing?

Tags: graphql

For my GraphQL app I'd like to save logs of certain resolved fields. Because the users can view these logs themselves, should that be considered apart of a mutation instead of a query?

Since it's not the application's focus I'd assume that using a mutation is overkill, but I'm not sure if there's some sort of side effects I'm going to run into by modeling it in such a way.

The other questions I've read didn't really answer this question, so sorry if this seems like a duplicate.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189364/shouldnt-the-login-be-a-query-in-graphql/50190570#50190570)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually Graphql Queries & Mutations do the same thing but however differ in the way the resolvers are executed.

For the following Queries:

```
{
  user {
    name
  }
  posts {
    title
  }
}
```

The GraphQL implementation has the freedom to execute the field entries in whatever order it deems optimal. [see here](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Normal-and-Serial-Execution).

For the following Mutations:

```
{
  createUser(name: $String) {
    id
  }
  addPost(title: $String) {
    id
  }
}
```

The GraphQL implementation would execute each Mutation *sequentially*. [see here](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Mutation)

Par from this, the Mutation keyword is just a bit of syntax to say "hey this is gonna edit or create something". I think here, in your case, its a better decision to perform a Query & store the event in your Audit log. Exposing the fact that the Query stores an audit log is an implementation-specific detail & clients shouldn't know about it.

Comment: This makes sense. Mutations are more for what the client-data creating/editing content wise. Side effects like logging and saving should be fine, then. Appreciated!

Comment: While the difference between the two operations is largely conceptual, there *is* in fact a difference in how they are executed. The fields of the mutation root type are resolved *sequentially* while the fields of any other type, including the query root type, are resolved in parallel. This ensures execution order if you have multiple mutation fields in a single operation.

Comment: @DanielRearden hey thanks for the input, have you got a reference to this ? I'll update my answer

Comment: @DanStarns See the spec [here](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Normal-and-Serial-Execution) and [here](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Mutation).