# Calling react-query method outside the body of a function component

Tags: graphql, react-query, graphql-codegen

So, I've been searching the internet for an example of a react-query function called outside the body of the function component; however, I was unable to find a sample.

I have a query type of GraphQL, and I am waiting for a value from the form that I could pass on. So I needed to call it inside the onSubmit function of Formik.

I have generated my hooks with [GraphQL Codegen](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/). Since we cannot call the react-hooks outside the function, I am uncertain how I can do this.

So, this is my react-hook for the query

```
const [{ data, fetching, stale, error, extensions, operation }] = useForgotPasswordQuery({ variables: { email: "value from the form" } });
```

Unlike with the mutation, it returns a function wherein I could use to call outside the function.

```
const [, forgotPassword] = useForgotPasswordMutation();

...
<Formik initialValues={{ email: '' }} onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors }) => {
    const response = await forgotPassword({ email: values.email });
}}>
```

I'd like to know on this use case, I cannot use query type? Or this is a way that I am unaware.

I've read here in the [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52551263/2637261) that the convention:

> Query — for querying data (SELECT operations)
>
> Mutation — for creating new and updating/deleting existing data (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)

In a way, this convention makes sense to me and I want to implement it. So I am trying to do it using the query rather than the mutation.

Comment: Would the ‘enabled’ option of a query be any help? To run it based on some conditio.

Comment: @JakubKotrs, sorry, what `enabled` option are you talking about?

Comment: The useQuery hook accepts “enabled” as option. Your question sounded like you want to delay a query until a certain condition is met and enabled option is ideal for that.

Comment: Oh, you mean the `pause`, @JakubKotrs? Hmm, I thought this has something to do with the SSR. I am not sure what's the `enabled` property you are referring to. I checked the properties being accepted to the generated query method, and I cannot see it.

Comment: No, it’s enabled, see here https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the issue was with the `useMutation`. What you have read is also true for `react-query` https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations